# Unpack list and change elements

Tags: python

Take the following 2 cases:

```
>>> a, b = [[None, None]]*2
>>> print(a, b)

[None, None] [None, None]


>>> a[0] = 1
>>> print(a, b)

[1, None] [1, None]
```

&

```
>>> a, b = [[None, None], [None, None]]
>>> print(a, b)

[None, None] [None, None]


>>> a[0] = 1
>>> print(a, b)

[1, None] [None, None]
```

1. I don't understand why the first case does not exhibit the same behavior as the second case since `[[None, None]]*2 == [[None, None],[None, None]]` returns `True`.

I suspect it's because when the list is multiplied, the new components will point to the values from the first components. How sane is this?

2. How can I make the first case behave just like the second one?

Comment: Yes, thank you. The proposed solution there is: `a, b = [[None, None] for _ in range(2)]`.

Comment: You can verify this by using id() method ```a, b = [[None, None]]*2
a[0] = 1
print(a, b)
print(id(a[0]),id(b[0]))```